# Ideal inline dynamic CSS injection

Tags: theme-development, wp-enqueue-style, css

There is a code in [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_add_inline_style) that dynamically load custom script.

```
<?php
function my_styles_method() {
    wp_enqueue_style(
        'custom-style',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/custom_script.css'
    );
        $color = get_theme_mod( 'my-custom-color' ); //E.g. #FF0000
        $custom_css = "
                .mycolor{
                        background: {$color};
                }";
        wp_add_inline_style( 'custom-style', $custom_css );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_styles_method' );
?>
```

I actually need to load only dynamic CSS part (`$custom_css`) and I don't need to load custom_script.css. According to [this document](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2011/12/12/use-wp_enqueue_scripts-not-wp_print_styles-to-enqueue-scripts-and-styles-for-the-frontend/) hook like `wp_print_styles` is discouraged. What would be the best way to load inline style in WordPress. Maybe I am missing something.

I have rejected `wp_head` also from the same reason as `wp_print_styles`.

Comment: Are you using the default `style.css` stylesheet from the theme? If that's the case you could attach your inline styles to it. If not, if you pass `'/'` to `wp_enqueue_style` as the second argument, the inline styles will be printed directly in the head.

Comment: Yes, `wp_enqueue_style( 'slug', get_stylesheet_uri() );` is good solution since `style.css` is required in any theme. The **inline** styles will just follow. Would you like to add this answer @LuisSanz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`wp_add_inline_style`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_style/) needs to be tied to an existing stylesheet in order to work properly. The inline styles will only be printed when the stylesheet they are attached to is enqueued. This is quite handy to control the scope of the inline styles. If the idea is to have them printed globally, the safest handle to tie them to is that of the active theme main stylesheet.

The way to attach the inline scripts to a stylesheet is by passing that stylesheet handle as the first parameter to `wp_add_inline_style`. The stylesheet handles may change depending on the theme and also depending on the viewed page, so they have to be found out. An easy way to know the full list of stylesheets and their handles loaded for a given page is using the following code:

```php
global $wp_styles;
echo '<pre>' . var_export( wp_list_pluck( $wp_styles->registered, 'src', 'handle' ), true ) . '</pre>';
```

Supposing the theme's main stylesheet handle is `'active-theme-style'`, then the call would be:

`wp_add_inline_style( 'active-theme-style', $custom_css );`

Some old or badly written themes might not load the css in a proper way. In that case, it's safer to enqueue a stylesheet. If that's not an option, this will work:

```php
wp_enqueue_style( 'any-handle', '/' );
wp_add_inline_style( 'any-handle', $css );
```

It feels a bit hacky but the alternative, printing a style tag directly to `wp_head`, is not good either.

Comment: the `wp_enqueue_style( 'any-handle', '/' );` would also yield the browser errors in my case so definitely not an option.

Comment: Does it? And if you pass `true` instead? The only check that it's done in `wp_enqueue_style` is a simple `if ( $src ) {}`. If it still throws an error I will edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Only to append the solution from @luis-sanz, I will add the note that every theme has to have the `style.css` file enqueued. Following the example https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_add_inline_style from the codex, we can use `get_stylesheet_uri()` function and append the dynamic CSS data using the `wp_add_inline_style` function in the following way.

```
<?php
function my_styles_method() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'active-theme-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );

    $color = get_theme_mod( 'my-custom-color' ); //E.g. #FF0000
    $custom_css = ".mycolor{ background: {$color}; }";
    wp_add_inline_style( 'active-theme-style', $custom_css );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_styles_method' );
?>
```

Must admit the usage of the `'/css/custom_script.css'` custom script is absolutely not needed, and the dynamic script will go just after the default style inclusion of the `<head>` section.